# Render input form with mutations

Tags: vue.js

Vue 2, I am trying to render text from input, and add, not override, the new number when pressing the button. Not sure how to pass in the data from here.

```js
let mutations = {
changeNumber(state, number) {
state.count = state.count + number 
}
}
    
const store = new Vuex.Store ({
mutations,
state: {
number: ""
}})

Vue.component('some-component', {
template: 
`<div>
<input 
value="Button" 
type="button" 
@click="$store.commit('changeNumber', number)" 
>
<input type="number" v-model="number">
<p>{{ $store.state.number }}
</p>
</div>
` 
})
     
new Vue({
el: '#app',
store
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your mutation to be

```
changeNumber(state, number) {
state.number += number 
}
```

Also define your data in the Vue definition

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data() {
 return {
  number: 0,
};
},
store
})
```

Template section

```
    Vue.component('some-component', {
    template: 
    `<div>
    <input 
    value="Button" 
    type="button" 
    @click="$store.commit('changeNumber', number)" 
    >
    <input type="number" v-model="number">
    <p>{{ number }}
    </p>
    </div>` 
})
```

Comment: Thanks, how to add together and render the current number with the number from input? @Amaarrockz

Comment: im trying to add the previous  with new number..

let mutations = {
  changeNumber(state, number) {
state.number = number 
}
  }

watch: {
    number

Comment: That's easy pls check my edited code...I have modified the mutation

Comment: Let me know if that works..if yes pls do accept the answer ...thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two issues:

1. Your mutation was trying to access `state.count` but all that existed was `state.number` (which started out as an empty string `""`.  Change this to `count: 0`:

   ```js
   const store = new Vuex.Store ({
      mutations,
      state: {
         count: 0
   //    ^^^^^^^^  FIX 1
      }
   })
   ```
2. Next, in your component, you need a `number` property in `data()` that corresponds to `v-model="number"` for the input text box so that you type into the text box, it will store the value there.  Without this, you won't have anything to pass to your mutation.

   ```js
   Vue.component('some-component', {
      template: 
         `<div>
            <input 
               value="Button" 
               type="button" 
               @click="$store.commit('changeNumber', number)" 
            >
            <input type="number" v-model="number">
            <p>{{ $store.state.number }}</p>
         </div>`, 

      data() {
         return {
            number: null,
         }
      },
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  FIX 2
   })
   ```

Also it's good practice to indent your code so that it's more readable.